# How do i make a particular color glow when using two colors in a brick texture? (Eevee)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, emission, shader-nodes

I only want to make the cyan strips glow. (Currently quite new to the shader editor)

[image]

Comment: you need to plug your Brick Texture into the Emission Color input of the BSDF and in the Render panel, enable Bloom (if you are in Eevee)

Comment: Thanks @moonboots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to plug your *Brick Texture* into the *Emission Color* input of the *Principled BSDF*. And if you are in Eevee, in the *Render* panel, enable *Bloom*. Increase the *Strength* of the emission if you want to see the bloom effect. To control the way the *Brick Texture* is projected on the object surface, you'll need to plug *(Input) Texture Coordinate > (Vector) Mapping > Brick Texture*.